# How to extract value of javascript variable using python lxml

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, lxml

I am trying to get the value of a javascript variable within an html page. I have figured out how to get the text of all script tags but can't seem to figure out how to get the text of a specific variable within a script tag. Does anyone know how to get the text of a javascript variable?

The following is an example of what I'm trying to parse from. I'm trying to get the value of "var d"

```
<div id="box" style="position:absolute;z-index:6;left:px;top:450px;"></div> 
    <script language="javascript"> 
    function showTooltip(element, town_name, p, points, a, town_type){
        var t = $('tt');
        t.style.top = (-75 + element.offsetTop) +  'px';
        t.style.left = (25 + element.offsetLeft) + 'px';
        t.style.backgroundImage="url('images/odd.png')";
        t.innerHTML = '<font color=#AD4100>' + unescape(town_name) + '<br/>' + unescape(p) + '<br/>' + points + '<br/>' + unescape(a) + '<br/>' + unescape(town_type) + '</font>';
        t.show();
    }
    function hideTooltip(){
        $('tt').hide();
    }
var d = [[1490.77265625,1373.4140625,30983,'TownID: 30983','GREY','circle_grey.png',1248,'planet x\'s city 5','','N/A'],[1186.45390625,1538.265625,33009,'TownID: 33009','GREY','circle_grey.png',1150,'wendyshome','','N/A'],[1234.496875,856.18203125,31646,'TownID: 31646','GREY','circle_grey.png',1312,'...','','N/A'],[1041.30078125,812.55859375,35358,'TownID: 35358','GREY','circle_grey.png',1207,'Waterville','','N/A'],
```

The following is a snippet of my code that gets the text of all script tags.

```
for element in page.iter('script'):
    scriptText = element.text_content()
print(scriptText)
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use string processing on `scriptText` once you have that extracted. `lxml` cannot help you any more here.

If `var d` is the last entry in the script, you could use:

```
var_d_source = scriptText.split('var d =', 1)[-1].rsplit(';', 1)[0].strip()
```

which should give you everything after `var d =` up to the last semicolon.

You'd then convert the value to Python with the `json` module:

```
var_d_value = json.loads(var_d_value)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the last variable, I'll try playing around with what you posted. Thank you for the post, I appreciate it.